# Python Beautiful Soup Web Scraping Specific Numbers

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

On [this page](http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/gametracker/boxscore/NFL_20140914_NE@MIN) the final score (number) of each team has the same class name `class="finalScore"`.

When I call the final score of the away team (on top) the code calls that number without a problem.  If ... favLastGM = 'A'

When I try to call the final score of the home team (on bottom) the code gives me an error. If ... favLastGM = 'H'

Below is my code:

```
import pickle
import math
import urllib2
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

#Last Two Game info Home [H] or Away [A]
favLastGM = 'A' #Higher week number 2

#Game Info (Favorite) Last Game Played - CBS Sports (Change Every Week)
favPrevGMInfoUrl = 'http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/gametracker/boxscore/NFL_20140914_NE@MIN'
favPrevGMInfoHtml = urlopen(favPrevGMInfoUrl).read()
favPrevGMInfoSoup = BeautifulSoup(favPrevGMInfoHtml)
if favLastGM == 'A': #This Gives Final Score of Away Team - Away Score
    favScore = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find_all("td", { "class" : "finalScore" })
elif favLastGM == 'H':
    favScore = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find_all("td", { "class" : "finalScore" })[1]
else:
    print("***************************************************")
    print("NOT A VALID ENTRY - favLastGM  !")
    print("***************************************************")


print ("Enter: Total Points Allowed from Favored Team Defense for last game played: "),
print favScore[0].text
```

This is the error I get if favLastGM = 'H'

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/jcmcdonald/Desktop/FinalScoreTest.py", line 26, in 
>       print favScore[0].text   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 905, in
>   **getitem**
>       return self.attrs[key] KeyError: 0

Comment: You are trying to read the second element (`[1]`) in a one element long list. And looking further down your code, when `favLastGM == 'H'`, then line 18 (`print favScore[0].text`) will crash, because `favScore` is not a list (or iterable)

Comment: Yes I am. How else can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just two elements with `class="finalScore"`, the first is the score of the home team, the second is the score of the away team:

```
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> favPrevGMInfoUrl = 'http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/gametracker/boxscore/NFL_20140914_NE@MIN'
>>> 
>>> favPrevGMInfoSoup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(favPrevGMInfoUrl))
>>> score = [item.get_text() for item in favPrevGMInfoSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "finalScore"})]
>>> score
[u'30', u'7']
```

FYI, instead of `.find_all("td", {"class": "finalScore"})`, you can use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors): `.select("td.finalScore")`.

Comment: any way to separate the two numbers? to call just 30 or just 7?

Comment: @jcmcdonald yup, get them by index, e.g. something like this would work: `score[favLastGM != 'H']`

Comment: @jcmcdonald in other words, if you need the "home" score, use `score[0]`, if an "away" score - use `score[1]`.

Comment: gotcha Thanks! and you would recommend using CSS selector? instead of .find_all?

Comment: @jcmcdonald good, once you'll get used to the CSS selector syntax, you'll feel more powerful! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are assigning different types of objects to `favScore`.  So in the first case, where you have:

```
if favLastGM == 'A': #This Gives Final Score of Away Team - Away Score
    favScore = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find_all("td", { "class" : "finalScore" })
```

You end up with a list...

```
faveScore = [<td class="finalScore">30</td>, <td class="finalScore">7</td>]
```

Whereas in the second case, where you have:

```
elif favLastGM == 'H':
    favScore = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find_all("td", { "class" : "finalScore" })[1]
```

You end up with a BeautfulSoup element...

```
favScore = <td class="finalScore">7</td>
```

You could fix this by doing (note the `[0]`):

```
if favLastGM == 'A': #This Gives Final Score of Away Team - Away Score
    favScore = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find_all("td", { "class" : "finalScore" })[0]
elif favLastGM == 'H':
    favScore = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find_all("td", { "class" : "finalScore" })[1]
```

And then at the end do:

```
print favScore.text
```

Answer (score 0):

I slight extension to @alecxe's answer, with explicit selection of *home* and *away* teams (instead on relying on the implicit ordering of the array):

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

favPrevGMInfoUrl = 'http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/gametracker/boxscore/NFL_20140914_NE@MIN'

favPrevGMInfoSoup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(favPrevGMInfoUrl))

home_score = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find("tr", {"class": "teamInfo homeTeam"}).find("td", {"class": "finalScore"}).get_text()
away_score = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find("tr", {"class": "teamInfo awayTeam"}).find("td", {"class": "finalScore"}).get_text()

print home_score, away_score
```